# How do i flip a 2d array from top to bottom?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to flip a 2d array from top to bottom.

E.G.   1,2,3

```
    4,5,6

    7,8,9

    into

    7,8,9

    4,5,6

    1,2,3
```

Comment: Can you provide any code you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide you the code as SO is not intended for this, but I will show you the steps necessary :

1. Create a second 2D array of the same dimensions of the first one
2. Loop over the first array backwards and copy each row at `size - index - 1` to the second array
3. Replace the first array with the second array

Answer (score 0):

```
 void flipArrays(int[][] arrays)
{
   int[][] result = new int[arrays.length][arrays[0].length];

   for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
   {
      for(int y = 0; y < arrays[0].length; y++)
      {
          result[i][y] = arrays[arrays.length - i - 1][y];
      }
   }
}
```

I will guide you how I solve this problem. You can do it in Math/pseudo-code, then covert it to your code.

1. Create a temp array, which is using for containing flip value from original array, so you will not override value of original array.
2. Pass last row of original array to the first row of temp array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointer method.

Use one pointer ( simply an integer variable) at row 0 and another in row n-1. Then swap the elements in them. Then increment the first one and decrement the second one. Until they point to the same row or until the first one is greater than second one you keep doing this.

Space complexity: `O(1)` Time complexity: `O(row*col)`

***Pseudocode***

```
start := 0
end   := row-1
while start < end
begin
     for each colvar in [0..col-1]
        swap arr[start,colvar] , arr[end,colvar]
     start <- start + 1
     end   <- end - 1
end
```